# I have a rectangular table. Can I cut it into 3 pieces to create a removable center leaf?

Tags: wood, table

The table is pretty simple: 4 legs, pine, 33" x 71". It's just too long for our space. I'd like to cut it down so it's square (or close to square) the majority of the time, but not give up the extra capacity when we have company.

Looks like table slides are readily available, but I haven't been able to find evidence of anyone else done this before. Is this a bad idea/not worth the effort on a decent but inexpensive table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Making good cuts is going to be the trickiest part.

If you have a large table saw that can accommodate the table top that will give you the best results. Otherwise you can use a straight edge with a sharp, fine toothed blade in a circular saw.  Use painter's tape over where you are going to cut. Mark the line then score the line a couple of times with a sharp utility knife to reduce chip out. If you can rent or borrow a good track saw that would be better at making a straight cut and minimizing tear out.

Next you'll need to attach hardware the pieces. Check out Woodworkers Hardware http://www.wwhardware.com/fasteners-table-hardware/table-hardware/table I've gotten a few things from there and they have good prices and variety. I would use a combination of the leaf alignment pins to align the leaf and the table slides.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the legs, cutting it once and creating a drop-leaf at one end might be easier.

But to be honest, I can't think of many situations where selling one table and buying another is not a more practical solution for a person wondering if converting a table is possible. I would consider the conversion  moderately difficult. Furniture making requires a high degree of craft and finish.